# WinService, startup and network

Tags: .net, networking, windows-services

I'm writing in .NET a windows service that, at windows startup, executes some network operations. I noticed that my service starts before the network is up.
How can I check the network connectivity? Or, better, how can I check if the dhcp gave me an ip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [CodeProject article describing one method to detect the network status](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/NetworkStatus.aspx), including tracking when the network availability changes.

It is built on top of the framework's [NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getisnetworkavailable.aspx) method and the [NetworkChange class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkchange.aspx).

Comment: the method NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable() is exactly what I needed.
Now it works perfectly! Thanks ;)